# Rearranging Git Commits

Tags: git, github, git-merge, pull-request

I am working on a feature branch `B` which I branched off `master`. `origin/master` is now ahead of `B`. I want to merge my branch `B` onto `origin/master` but I want to pretend that as  if I just branched off the `HEAD` off `origin/master` and all my commits on `B` go on to top off `master` when do I the merge. And, I want to do this such that it preserves the GitHub pull request diffs etc. How can I do this?

Comment: Is branch `B` a local branch, or has it been pushed up the a remote?

Comment: The syntax can be tricky, but the command you're looking for is `git rebase`

Comment: @mwarsco: The `git rebase` command is only usable if the `B` branch has never been pushed to another remote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming nobody else has worked on / based any work on `B`. The command you are looking for is:

```
git checkout B
git rebase origin/master
git push -f origin B
```